# Portable function in C (with no assembly) that returns the size of its stack frame

Tags: c, embedded, stack-frame

Write a portable function in C (with no assembly) that returns the size of its stack frame

```
int stackframe_size()
{

}
```

Attempted solving it as below - This function returns 228 bytes when compiled with VS 2010. Is there a way to verify its correctness?

```
    int stackframe_size(int run)
    {
        int i ;

        if(!run)
        {
            return ((int)(&i) - stackframe_size(++run));

        }
        return (int)(&i);

    }
```

Invoked as:

```
    int main()
    {
        printf("\nSize of stackframe_size() is: %d bytes",stackframe_size(0)) ;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: :) I asked this since I wanted  to check if there is a clever/cleaner way to do this without adding local variables that read argument addresses (say for instance using recursion technique).

Comment: Sounds like a good technique to me. Perhaps you should share that code, and explain how it works and the results you get.

Comment: You can't have such a *portable* function. An hypothetical whole-program optimizing compiler could *sometimes* generate code without any stack; and one could imagine some C compiler without stacks (but allocating all the call frames in some garbage collected heap, like SML/NJ did). So in principle, a stack is not even required. But I know no such weird C implementations without stacks!

Comment: Also, compilers are permitted to optimize a recursive function (e.g. using tail-calls)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - there's no tail-call here is there?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Example "weird" implementation: I use a complier for an embedded code that does not allow recursion - thus not truly compliant C.  The code, by static analysis _at compile time_, knows and assigns the address of each local variable.  The only _stack_ is the return address, which is known by the same analysis to not exceed a certain level.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of such implementation (I mentioned whole-program optimization). BTW,  what implementation is it?

Comment: The only other thing I'll point out - which I don't believe has been mentioned yet - is that your routine (the subtraction operation) assumes the second call to stackframe_size() will have its stack frame located in a physically lower memory address.  While this is generally (or even usually) true, it doesn't have to be.  As others have said, making this portable (even if you did an a>b comparison before the subtraction) is essentially a fool's errand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such *portable* function is possible.

Your attempt is probably about as close as you can get, but the pointer subtraction has undefined behavior. More generally, `p1 - p0`, where `p0` and `p1` are pointers to distinct objects, has undefined behavior.

Except that your code subtracts to `int` values that are the result of conversions from addresses. Direct subtraction of the pointers is more likely to work -- and the pointers should be of type `char*` or `unsigned char*`. There are many implementations where `int` is too small to hold a converted pointer, and some where pointers have a more complicated representation than you assume, and converting them to even a sufficiently large integer type will not necessarily give you a meaningful result.

There are real-world C implementations that don't use a "stack" in the sense of a contiguous region of memory on which "stack frames" are pushed and popped. (There has to be a "stack" in the sense of a first-in last-out data structure, but the way that "stack" is implemented is entirely unspecified.)  Some IBM mainframe implementations, for example, allocate memory for a function call via something like a heap, so that there is no defined relationship between the addresses of the local variables for two such calls.

You can probably write a function in pure C (without assembly language) that gives you the size of a stack frame *for a particular implementation*. But since the C language itself has no concept of a "stack frame" (the standard doesn't even use the word "stack"), it cannot be done portably.

Comment: Kudos for "No such portable function is possible" - C implementations aren't even _required_ to have a stack.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to check if there is a clever/cleaner way to do this without adding local variables

You could use `&run` instead of `&i` - that would save you a local variable.

> Is there a way to verify its correctness?

Use a debugger! Check the stack pointer register at the spots you care about, watch the spills take place, etc.