# Returning address of a local variable directly using address of operator vs using pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I'm aware of the fact that you should never return the address of a local variable from a function. But while demonstrating the fact I faced a problem. Consider the following program:

```
int *test()
{
    int x = 12;
    int *p = &x;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int *p = test();
    printf("%p",p);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints an address like `0061fed0` as expected. But if I return the address of x directly using `&` i.e. if the `test` function is changed as follows:

```
int *test()
{
    int x = 12;
    return &x;
}
```

then the output becomes `00000000`. So, can you please explain what is happening here? I'm using gcc compiler that comes bundled with Code:: Blocks 17.12 IDE in windows 10.

Regarding Duplicate Questions:
Suggested duplicate question:
[C - GCC generates wrong instructions when returning local stack address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967840/c-gcc-generates-wrong-instructions-when-returning-local-stack-address)
Explains the behaviour of using the address of operator directly but doesn't address the scenario where a pointer variable is used to return the address of a local variable, which is explained here in StoryTeller's answer: "The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - GCC generates wrong instructions when returning local stack address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967840/c-gcc-generates-wrong-instructions-when-returning-local-stack-address)

Comment: also : [Why does gcc return 0 instead of the address of a stack allocated variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290049/why-does-gcc-return-0-instead-of-the-address-of-a-stack-allocated-variable)

Comment: Undefined behavior is behavior which is not defined. The compiler isn't obliged to produce any meaningful code. Speculating about why it generated a certain flavour of meaningless code isn't particularly interesting.

Comment: @Lundin "The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime." I didn't know that. That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, from the point of view of C language specification, that's a valid outcome.

> **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects** (emphasis mine)
>
> [2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2) The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution
>   during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object
>   exists, has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value
>   throughout its lifetime. If an object is referred to outside of its
>   lifetime, the behavior is undefined. **The value of a pointer becomes
>   indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the
>   end of its lifetime.**

Therefore the value that function returns is indeterminate in either case. You cannot predict what it will be, or even use it in a meaningful way. A program that uses an indeterminate value has undefined behavior, anything can occur.

So what your compiler does is return null when you return the address of a local directly. It's a valid value according to the C language itself, since the object is dead soon anyway. But it has the benefit of likely crashing your program early in a modern hosted implementation, and allowing you to fix a bug.

Comment: "The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime." - That's what I was looking for. Thanks.